# Golang - what is the order if every cases in switch case evaluates?

Tags: go, switch-statement

Imagine we have switch case

```
  switch {
  case true:
   fmt.Println(1)
  case true:
   fmt.Println(2)
```

What will be output ?

I heard that golang will pick pseudo-random expression, but I tested in go-playground and got that it will stick to order from top to bottom, so it will be 1 in output

Comment: The first one https://go.dev/tour/flowcontrol/10

Comment: Go picks randomly for `select`, not for `switch`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first case that matches the switch statement is executed:

> In an expression switch, the switch expression is evaluated and the case expressions [...] are evaluated left-to-right and top-to-bottom; the first one that equals the switch expression triggers execution of the statements of the associated case; the other cases are skipped.

https://go.dev/ref/spec#Switch_statements

> I heard that golang will pick pseudo-random expression

The pseudo-random selection happens for *select* statements when multiple branches are ready to proceed, not for *switch*.